# How to ignore web crawlers?

Tags: html, ip, web-crawler, bots

I have a page that count how many times is visited by a user (registered, guest, every kind of users...).

So I update a field on the database every time the page is viewed; yes, also if the page is refreshed quickly, but I don't mind about this.

Of course, when some bots/crawler scans my website they will increment this value, and I'll get rid about this. So, is there a list of IP addresses to ignore? Or some mechanism that can help me to do it?

Comment: @Kumar it's a good starting point (as I mention in my answer) but the PITA crawlers/bots are those which generally ignore robots.txt

Comment: @marto What do you mean by PITA bots

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is with ajax. Most crawlers don't parse javascript.

Comment: Oh...yeah this is a good point :) With "Most" what do you mean? Are there crawlers that parse js?

Comment: Google are capable to parse javascript. But **i think** it only does that on pages with `#!` in the url (like twitter).

Comment: Anyway, since google is suposed to respect `robots.txt`, you should use it as well. With it you can disable just the page of the statistics if you want.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo, even though crawlers don't parse javascript, the page itself would still be crawled no?

Comment: @Parecier yes, but the request to update the visitors count would not be triggered (if he implements it in ajax). Also, the `#!` mentioned above, if i'm not mistaken, just let google know that there's another plain html version of that content for it to parse (that you have to provide).

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses can change so it's not be the best way to detect whether or not a visitor is a bot. Instead, I suggest looking at the user-agent string in the HTTP request parameters.

Here's a list of user-agent strings: http://www.user-agents.org/ . Look specifically under the type R for "robots, crawler, spider".

Comment: what about the bad crawlers trying to get people's emails? they would not send user-agent info in the request :p

Comment: @hugo_leonardo, that's a different question altogether

Answer (score 1):

Most people don't have a static IP address. Have you setup a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to deny access to crawlers/bots? You could periodically query your log files to try and identify those which don't respect robots.txt, though the user agent is easily spoofed/changed.

Comment: He doesn't want to block bots, he wants to ignore them in his visit stats.